# Facebook API : create page - "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I am trying to create a facebook page with graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating

However, I keep getting error - **"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action."**

Permissions provided are ***['publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'pages_show_list', 'publish_pages', 'business_management'];***

What permissions are needed ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started#create-page - “Your app must be reviewed and approved to use the Pages API” - that the case? Plus, I don’t think this is available for normal users, they must be business manager users or something like that.